# SQL Server: how to limit access to encrypted column, even from dba?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm new to database encryption. We have a requirement to encrypt some columns in various tables which show sensitive information. The problem we have is, the data should not be seen by anyone with access to the database or its certificate and symmetric keys (not even dbas), and only some users of the application which query the data in the database should see the information.

So we have come up with this:

- 1 symmetric key created for each table with encrypted columns
- all the keys protected by a certificate, and stored procedures accessing these certificates are now defined with:

  ```
  OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Key_SalaryTable 
  DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SystemCertificate 
  WITH PASSWORD = 'password';
  ```

(which means the password for the certificate which is used to open the `Key_SalaryTable` is hardcoded into the stored procedure)

But there is a problem, any database administrator can just view the stored procedure or call the stored procedure directly to know how to open the key to view the salary table

Even if we restrict each user's access to the stored procedure, a dba can easily override that and extract information before setting the restrictions back again and no one will know the information has been compromised.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: You need to keep the password to your `Key_SalaryTable` on your application not on the db itself, and pass it as a parameter to the stored procedure.

Comment: but i think we can't pass passwords as parameters into stored procedures unless we change it to dynamic. Please see
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/369270/open-symmetric-master-key-password-parameterization

Comment: Please see also: can't pass key into stored procedure http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/439d57c6-4f0b-4590-991b-97d6881409b3/problem-opening-symmetric-key-with-passed-password?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: As the thread indicates, you need to resort to dynamic SQL.

Comment: is there a better solution? dynamic sql doesn't seem to be a good practice

Comment: The alternative is to execute the `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` / `CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY` commands from the application itself not in the stored procedure. BTW, the KEY remains open on the session until its closed or the session terminates. Make sure the connection between your application and the db is encrypted "[on the wire](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898)".

Comment: You could encrypt the stored procedures that contain the sensitive password - those encrypted stored procedures cannot be seen in source code anymore, not even by a dba. Just make sure you store the source code for those stored procedures (including the password used to encrypt them) somewhere safe!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the suggestion, but is there a way to prevent the dba from calling the stored procedure directly?

Comment: @wdosanjos can u pls post your comment as an answer? it's been about one day and i guess I'll probably follow your suggestion of running the Open Symmetric Key statement at the start of each connection to sensitive data. But I wonder where to store the Open statement's password? would it be in asp.net's web.config as part of an encrpyted section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative is to execute the `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` / `CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY` commands from the application itself not in the stored procedure. BTW, the KEY remains open on the session until its closed or the session terminates. Make sure the connection between your application and the db is encrypted "[on the wire](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898)".

On the ASP.NET side you can keep the password on an encrypted web.config section.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Password from the application as parameter to the stored procedure,
Password as parameter is possible only by using dynamic query

> --Open the Symmetric key
>
> DECLARE @open nvarchar(200)
>
> SET @open = 'OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Key_SalaryTable DECRYPTION BY
>   CERTIFICATE SystemCertificate WITH PASSWORD =''' + @password + ''''
>   EXEC sp_executesql @open
>
> -- Queries
>
> --Close the Symmetric key
>      CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY Key_SalaryTable